Should Correlation Between Out-of-Sample Forecasts and Actual Values Be Included in Forecast Evaluation Alongside RMSE?
I'm currently evaluating the performance of a forecasting model using the Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) as the primary metric. I've noticed that some literature also includes the Pearson correlation coefficient between the out-of-sample forecasts and the actual values as part of the evaluation.
Does it make sense to include this correlation in my forecast evaluation? Does it provide any additional relevant information that RMSE does not capture? I'm particularly interested in whether correlation adds value in understanding the relationship between the forecasted and actual values, and if it's a standard practice to report both metrics together.
Any insights or best practices would be appreciated!

I think it may be useful to include, since RMSE requires more interpretation to understand (i.e. what is a high or low RMSE value).
Part of this depends on how you are calculating RMSE - is it from the difference between predicted and observed values, or from residuals of the linear model of observed ~ predicted.
If you are calculating RMSE the first way (which I would argue is the right way), then you may find high RMSE, but you could still have high correlation. For instance, consider a case where your model consistently predicts values that are higher than the observed values. These values may still be highly correlated to the observed values, while still being consistently wrong and having high RMSE. This might be a hint that your model structure is good, but that parameters values need retuning.

Yes, the RMSE is calculated by taking the difference between predicted and observed values. That is a helpful response, thanks.

If you are in the stage of experimenting and model development, then you can have a look at many different metrics and maybe correlation will give you some valuable insight.
However, if your models are ready and some forecasts have been produced, then no you should not consider correlation in your evaluation. If you compare forecasts using RMSE, you are effectively interested in finding the best mean forecasts for your observations. Including other metrics which are not designed to reward good forecasts of the mean will compromise your evaluation in the sense that the best mean forecast will have a harder time to demonstrate its quality.
Mixing many evaluation metrics without careful understanding of their meaning is a symptom of an ill-defined forecasting problem and a recipe for bad decisions.
